# jQuery Mobile Cannot read 'options' of undefined on trigger('pagecreate')

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am loading an external page into a div on my jqm page and in order to enhance it with the jQuery mobile styles I call trigge('pagecreate') on the div, this works from the console.

```
 $('#search-results-page').load('searchResults.php',{options:$.encodeJSON(data.options),search:$.encodeJSON(data.search)},function () {
        $(this).trigger('pagecreate',{options:{}});
        $.mobile.changePage('#search-results-page');
    });
```

It works if I put my code in a try catch block but if I don't then I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js:7535

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this error and it was because I was using jQuery 2.0.0

Try with jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: Same error when using panel first time, solved with your solution. Thanks!